# Converting a table from html file to pdf using xhtml2pdf

Tags: python, django, pdf, django-rest-framework, xhtml2pdf

Hi guys I am having a problem using xhtml2pdf.

I am following a tutorial and it worked (note: the data in the tutorial is hardcoded). So I change a bit of the code from the tutorial so I can fetch data from a database using django-rest-framework. When I run the project there were no errors but I typed the url to see my pdf file, its error 404.

here is my views.py

```
class GeneratePdf(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = DirectoryTb.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DirectoryTbSerializer

    def get(self, request, queryset, *args, **kwargs):
        pdf = render_to_pdf('directory.html', queryset)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

here is my urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'^pdf', GeneratePdf)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```